# Finding pathways enriched in Mus musculus

Tags: cytoscape

I am relatively new to Cytoscape Reactome FI plugin use. I have identified differentially expressed genes in mouse (Mus musculus) between two experimental conditions of my interest using DESeq analysis. I wish to identify the pathways that are enriched within these genes that are differentially expressed. I came across the Cytoscape's Reactome FI plugin which finds pathways and network patterns related to cancer and other types of diseases. Can one enter mouse genes into Reactome to identify enriched pathways?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I believe the Reactome FI network is human.  However, you can do what you want using the stringApp, which also includes the ability to perform enrichment on many species, including mouse.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks Scooter! I will check that out